# Use Django Filters in ModelViewSet which return serializer data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to combine 2 models: **City** and **Country** in order to have a filter like this: `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/geo/location-search/?name=Santa+Fe`

I have a ModelViewSet which return serializer data like this:

```
class LocationSearchAPI(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = City.objects.all().order_by('name')
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = CityListSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filter_class = LocationFilter

    def get_location_list(self, request):
        city_qs = City.objects.all().order_by('name')
        country_qs = Country.objects.all().order_by('name')
        result_qs = list(chain(country_qs, city_qs))

        sorted_list = sorted(result_qs, key=lambda instance: -instance.id)
        results = list()

        for item in sorted_list:
            item_type = item.__class__.__name__.lower()
            if isinstance(item, City):
                serializer = CityLocaliaztionSrl(item)
            if isinstance(item, Country):
                serializer = CountryLocaliaztionSrl(item)
            results.append({'type': item_type, 'data': serializer.data})
        return Response(results, status=200)
```

and this Filter's not work:

```
class LocationFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('type', 'data__name')
```

How can I use Django Filters in ModelViewSet which return serializer data, hope your guys help me.

Comment: can you please post desire output format?

Comment: Post the model and explain what you mean by it doesn’t work.